# How does Content Search WebPart do the User.Name comparison? based on Account, Name or GUID?

Tags: 2013, user-profile, active-directory, content-search-web-part, user-accounts

I have the following issue inside my SharePoint 2013 farm, regarding usernames' properties.

1. I have test farm + live farm. both farms are integrated with the same Active directory.
2. For some users i find that their Names are not the same on both farms. for example i have a username = `John Ejohn` while on the other farm its name =  `juhn Ejuhn`.. while the user have the same email & account (i got these info from the `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx` page from both farms).

[image]

3. now since on both farms i did not configure the User Profile service, so i can understand that the above issue could have been caused by this scenario; the user accessed certain farm, so a user profile get created for him inside `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx` page, then his username got changed on the AD level, and after that he access the other farm, so his user profile got created. and as a result the user have different Name on both farms, while his email and account are the same.

but my question, now i am planning to create some Content Search Web Parts on both farms, and i am going to specify criteria such as :-

```
OwnerOWSUSER:{User.Name}
```

to show items which have the Owner = login user. but i am not sure, will the above comparison be based on the Name, or on the Account or on the GUID? and could the above criteria under certain scenarios (as the scenario i specify above) fail to match the user? if his Name have been changed inside the AD?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/05/update-user-display-name-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell.html

How to Re-Sync All users from Active Directory?
To re-sync all user details, use this PowerShell script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-SPUser -Web http://web-app-url | Set-SPUser –SyncFromAD
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/ecbc9692-5703-4d1e-aba7-c6eb1b8a0ea4/user-name-change-user-information-list

---

**EDIT**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx

{User} or {User.Name}

Display name of the user who issued the query. For example, this value can be used to query content of the managed property Author.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but you did not answer my question regarding how the Content Search web part do the comparison for users ??. for example when i specify something as follow `OwnerOWSUSER:{User.Name}` inside the content search web-part criteria.. will the search be based on the username or Account or GUID??

Comment: See edit answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. so this mean if the display name of the user on the `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx` page does not match the updated display name on the AD, then using these criteria inside my content search web part  will not work `{User} or {User.Name}` is this correct? or if the user access a site collection with his updated display name, then his info on the ``/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx` will get updated too... second point is it more safer to use critiria such as `{User.SID}` to make sure it will not get changed??

Comment: but if it is safer to use `{User.SID}` ,, then can i extract the SID of the People o Group column?? as seems this criteria will never work, as the People or group column will return display name, while the `{User.SID}` will return the id of the user  as follow:- `OwnerOWSUSER:{User.SID}`

Comment: can you please advice on my above comments.

Comment: You can use OwnerOWSUSER:{User.Name}. Owner column will be the same because people picker will set user name.